# SQL SERVER Update table from tables with increment on some fields based on max

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012, ssms, updating

Table 1 -- Where information will be finally stored
Table 2 -- Updated information from Access

Table 1 :

| ProJ# | LOC_ID | OBJ_ID | OBJ_U_ID | OBJ_TYPE | OBJ_# | OBJ_V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 | A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 4 | 4 | A | 3 | null |
| A | 1 | 5 | 5 | A | 4 | null |
| A | 1 | 2 | 2 | B | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 1 | 1 | A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 2 | 2 | A | 2 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 2 | 2 | A | 2 | Null |
| A | 1 | 3 | 3 | B | 2 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 2 2nd | 2nd | C | 1 | null |

Table 2:

| LOCID | OBJ# | OBJV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 | 3 |

so what I am trying to do is update Table 1 with information from Table 2
if the LOCID = LOC_ID and OBJ# = OBJ_# and OBJ_TYPE = 'A' Update Set OBJ_V = OBJV
if not match insert into table 1. this is where i run into problems.

so on insert i need to get max(OBJ_ID) and +1 for every entry that will be inserted into table 1 from table 2.

my issue is that i runinto is that it will set them all to the same number.
ex: MAX(OBJ_ID ) will be 5 so next should be 6 then 7 ect...
but i get 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6 etc..
OBJ_ID , OBJ_U_ID  are the same for all OBJ_TYPE except C.

here is what im trying:

```
MERGE Table1 as T1 Using (
Select @PRoJect as ProN, OBJV, LOCID, OBJ# from TABLE2 where OBJ# is not null) AS S2
on
(T1.OBJ_# = S2.OBJ# and T1.LOC_ID = S2.LOCID and T1.PorJ# = S2.ProN and T1.OBJ_TYPE = 'A')
When Matched then Update Set
    T1.OBJ_V  = S2.OBJV
When Not Matched then Insert (
ProJ# , LOC_ID , OBJ_ID , OBJ_U_ID , OBJ_TYPE , OBJ_#  , OBJ_V
) Values (
@PRoJect , s2.locID , "NEED HELP HERE",  "NEED HELP HERE" , S2.OBJ#, S2.OBJV
);
```

i have tried many things none get me a result that is right.

I have tried multiple things to get this to work. some partial work but then break bad.

what im trying to get out is:

Sequential number for OBJ_ID on max value on insert.
so if max is 5  for LOC_ID = 1 and 2 for LOC_ID = 2
on insert it would look similar to this:

| LOC_ID | OBJ_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 10 |

the can be more the 2 LOC_ID

Comment: I started working on this, but there's something I don't understand. You are joining on LocId and ObjId. Then, if you don't find a match, you want to insert the LocId and calculate the ObjId. That mean that, in your above example, if Table 2 had LocId = 1 and ObjId = 10, your instructions indicate that you want to add that as LocId = 1 and ObjId = 6.  That seems problematic to me. Can you clarify?

Comment: In your expectd results all OBJ are different but in table_a there are repeated, this can be repeated?

Comment: so with my merge code that i have it can currently update the information just fine and it can insert if non existent. this works just like i want. but he problem i ran into during testing was when the OBJ_Type was not 'A. if there was an 'B' with OBJ_ID of 6. and last 'A' ID was 5. then upon adding the next 'A' ID would need to be 7. the obj_ID is the truly Unique ID.

Comment: I was debating if it would be easier to  just add another column to table 2. and  assign the OBJ_ID into Table 2 for inserting purpose

Comment: Not the Cleanest way to do it. but it works. first thing i did was copy/update Table 2 OBJ# from Table 1 OBJ ID where the IDs Matched. then that just left me with some nulls. then from there i got the highest OBJ_ID for each LOC_ID and saved as a variable, then i had it only select the OBJ# from table2 that where null and the ROW_Number() + Variable to get it to auto number the fields.  like i said ugly but seems to work.  if any one finds a cleaner way then updating table 2 from 1 then back i would extremally apricate it